# CreateEnvelope() throws exception. No message

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to create and send an envelope on the demo environment using the docusign C# API. I am using JWT as my OAuth2 flow. I am able to properly grab the access code needed to authorized my embedded signing.

The function CreateEnvelope fails and throws an exception. The exception shows no information other than that the function failed.
[Image of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6mWW.png)

Has anyone encountered a similar situation before? I have provided a snippet of the code below. Is there anything clearly wrong with how I may be trying to create the envelope?

```
    public static void DocusignFormatter()
    {
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(pdfFileInfo.fileBytes);
        doc.Name = pdfFileInfo.DocName;
        doc.DocumentId = "1";
        
        envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
        envDef.Documents.Add(doc);
        envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < signatureFields.Count; i++)
        {
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.Email = docRegistrant.Email;
            signer.Name = docApplicants[i].FirstName + " " + docApplicants[i].LastName;
            signer.RecipientId = $"{i+1}";
            signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
            List<MyPdfSignatureField> fields;
            signatureFields.TryGetValue(i, out fields);
            foreach (MyPdfSignatureField field in fields)
            {
                SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
                signHere.DocumentId = "1";
                signHere.PageNumber = field.PageNum.ToString();
                signHere.RecipientId = i.ToString();
                signHere.XPosition = field.XLocation.ToString();
                signHere.YPosition = field.YLocation.ToString();
                signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
            }
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
        }
        envDef.Status = "created";
        


        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(DocusignHelpers.OAuthBasePath);

        Configuration cfi = new Configuration(apiClient);
        

        cfi.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + DocusignHelpers.AccessToken);
        cfi.AccessToken = DocusignHelpers.AccessToken;
        cfi.Password = DocusignHelpers.Password;


        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(cfi);

        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(DocusignHelpers.AccountId, envDef);
```

[Caught Exception values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmemI.png)

Comment: Add an exception handler and posting the inner stack will help.  Also using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and getting the status in the response will help which is normally 200 OK and 400/500 if there is an error.  One way of isolating issue is to comment out some of your code (like where you are adding headers) to determine where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Inner exception is null, but the response code was a 400.
Maybe my url is incorrect

Comment: There is a TCP authentication using TLS before the HTTP request/response you will see in the sniffer data.  TLS 1/0/1.1 was discontinued in June this year and you must use TLS 1.2 or later.  The 400 error probably is due to using wrong version TLS.  Make sure you are using the latest API (dlls) that support TLS 1.2.  Also windows will default to TLS 1.0 unless yo uspecifically specify TLS 1.2.  The encryption mode of signature also must be supported by TLS 1.2.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this line:

```
envDef.EmailSubject = "Test, please sign.";
```

But that's not the reason for the exception, since you created it as "created" (draft) mode, but it would be the issue once you try to send it.

You may want to confirm the values of all your recipients and ensure you're not sending something that's not an email (for example) in an email field etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this friends.

My api url was incorrect.

My key confusion was that the auth endpoints have a separate base url than the rest of the RESTful API.

Authorization url for the demo was: https://account-d.docusign.com

The API client object actually has static fields that contain the urls for the different platforms demo, prod, staging.

I ended up using

```
ApiClient.Demo_REST_BasePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
```

Thank you all for the replies and help